# return multiple different values from single helper function?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

[image]

I have a helper `compare` that returns a css class that simply highlights the text. `"better"` makes it green, `"worse"` colors it red. Basically the function compares 2 numbers (the compare function thats commented out does the same as the ternary below it). How can i compare multiple values in the same helper function? I know i could just create a bunch more helper functions and compare all the data 1 by 1, but im sure theres a better way. Heres what the template looks like :

[image: http://img.prntscr.com/img?url=http://i.imgur.com/Bo8oTcO.png]

Answer (score 6):

Return the multiple values as an object from your helper then refer to the keys in your template.

js:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  compare(){
    return { key1: value1, key2: value2, ... keyN: valueN};
  }
});
```

html:

```
{{compare.key1}} etc...
```

Comment: Ty yea this is what i was thinking, was jw if there was a "Meteor" way

Comment: I'm not sure this is officially meteoric but I use this pattern all over the place and it works well.

Comment: this is great but what if i want to pass in a variable {{icon.color type}} ? it doesn't work

Comment: You can add parameters to the helper, i.e. `compare(p1,p2){...}` and then pass them in from your blaze template as `{{compare p1 p2}}`

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to pass them as arguments within the function definition itself, something like this should do the trick:

```
compare: function( number1, number2 ) {
  return number1 > number 2 ? "better" : "worse";
}
```